# Idle TeamCity agents dont take compatible tasks from queue

Tags: git, root, teamcity

I have new TeamCity 8.1.3 and one task in build queue and *compatible* enabled agent.
But agent is idle.

I tried to re-install teamcity, re-install buildAgent and install agent on another machine.
Tried to run agent as root. I read all agent logs and don't find any error; only warnings for not installed VCS tools (i need only git).

Why does the agent not take task to run?

Comment: Hi,  **Firstly** :- This is common scenario every time I upgrade Teamcity. I will leave it alone for few minutes and just check all the Teamcity and Agent services are started and try restarting both the Services and see it restart occurs successfully.  **Secondly** if You could add log " teamcity-server.log" and "teamcity-agent.log" I could further look into it. Some screenshots from your Teamcity UI would be useful to investigate. **Thirdly** Is your build agent machine able to access/connect teamcity on installed port .